# Get current zoom and center from mapbox in dash

Tags: python, mapbox, plotly-dash

I want to make an interactive map with dash. So I added a Scattermapbox to visualize some data.
To select which data is shown, I added a slider. and used a callback to redraw the map.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'place_no': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'lat': [50.941357, 50.941357, 50.941357, 50.932171, 50.932171, 50.932171],
                   'lon': [6.957768, 6.957768, 6.957768, 6.964412, 6.964412, 6.964412],
                   'year': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018, 2019],
                   'value': [20, 40, 60, 80, 60, 40]})


def get_map(df_map):
    fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df_map['lat'],
        lon=df_map['lon'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=df_map['value']
        ),
    ))
    fig.update_layout(
        mapbox_style="open-street-map",
        mapbox={'center': go.layout.mapbox.Center(lat=50.936600, lon=6.961497), 'zoom': 11}
    )
    return fig


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='map',
              figure=get_map(df[df['year'] == 2017])),
    dcc.Slider(id='year-picker',
               min=2017,
               max=2019,
               marks={2017: {'label': 2017}, 2018: {'label': 2018}, 2019: {'label': 2019}}
               ),
    html.Div(id='shown-week', style={'textAlign': 'center'})
], )


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='map', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='year-picker', component_property='value')]
)
def update_map(selected_year):
    filtered_df = df[df['year'] == selected_year]
    fig = get_map(filtered_df)
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

This worked out fine for now. And I get exact the result I expect.

[image: Screenshot Output]

But if move or zoom the map, and then select new data with the slider, the center and the zoom goes back to the initial values, which is very inconvenient.

Is there any way to get the center and zoom of the current view, so I can add it in the `update-layout` method?
Or is there any other way to save the current view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the `uirevision` property? If you set this property to a constant value when you update the figure, i.e.

```
fig['layout']['uirevision'] = 'some-constant'
```

the zoom etc. should stay the same. For details, see the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-uirevision).